# How to show that $k_1k_2 - k_0 > 0$?

Tags: inequality

> Let $a_1, a_2, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $ a_1 \neq 0,\, $
>    $a_2 \neq 0,\, $
>   $  a_1 > a_2,\, $
>   $ b \neq 0,\,$
>    $c \neq 0,\,$
>   and $ b_1 < b < b_2 < 2(a_1 - a_2)$,
>   where :
>   $$b_1 = \frac{2(a_1-a_2)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4a_1}{c}} + 1} \qquad b_2 = \frac{2(a_1-a_2)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4a_2}{c}} + 1}$$
>   Prove that $k_1k_2 - k_0 > 0,$
>   where :
>   $$k = \frac{a_1a_2c}{b^3(a_1-a_2)}\left(b+\frac{2(a_1-a_2)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4a_1}{c}} - 1}\right)\left(\frac{2(a_1-a_2)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4a_1}{c}} + 1}\right)$$
>   $$k_2 = \frac{(a_1+a_2)b^2+2c(a_1-a_2)^2}{(a_1-a_2)b}$$
>   $$k_1 = c\left[\frac2b -\frac{1}{a_1 - a_2}\right][(a_1 + a_2)b + (a_1-a_2)c]$$
>   $$k_0 = -k(b-b_1)(b-b_2)$$

This was a Bonus question in a test I took last week, I computed $k_1k_2$ and kept doing circular simplifications but I never reached something that looks like $k_0$.

Is there some kind of observation to make to turn this into a less painful problem ?

Comment: "this was a Bonus question in a test I took last week" I am curious, in which (kind of) curriculum?

Comment: @Did Advanced ODE's, there is many problems with this same concept, you can use the results to show positive definiteness of some complicated lyapunov functions

Comment: This might be homogeneous in $c$ hence solving the case $c=1$ would suffice. Apart from that...